# Is it possible to use a single docker volume to map to two different directories?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, vscode-remote, mounted-volumes

I am using VS Code, Remote Development Containers, and Docker to create development environments within containers. Everything works fine, but I did notice that when working with different projects that doing things such as `yarn install` means having to download the npm modules each time. Of course, once a container image does this they are stored in the cache, specifically `/usr/local/share/.cache/yarn/v6`.

When I attempted to mount that folder to the host machine `yarn install` would start to fail too often, stating that it was having trouble downloading the package due to a bad network connection (the connection was just fine). So, I created a volume instead and everything worked just fine.

The problem I am running into is that I also want to share other folders in the volume so that multiple containers use the same cache for things such as NuGet packages. I was hoping to somehow have my volume look like so:

```
mysharedvolume/yarn => /usr/local/share/.cache/yarn/v6
mysharedvolume/nuget => /wherever/nuget/packages/are/cached
mysharedvolume/somefile.config => /wherever/somefile.config
```

This does not seem to be the way volumes work in docker, all of the files are mixed up at the root of the volume (there is no subdirectories). Of course, I can't simply map the entire /usr folder or anything like that, that's crazy.

Before I go off and create different volumes for each cache and config files, is there a way to do this with a single shared volume?